# Unpacking a list in numpy[square brackets]

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Consider the following small example, dramatically simplified compared to my actual use case:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.arange(125).reshape(5,5,5)
i = np.where( np.mod(z[0], 3) == 0 )
```

So that `i` is a tuple of 2 arrays.

Now I can use i to index into a slice of z

```
z[0][i]
# array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24])
z[1][i]
# array([25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49])
```

I would like to get the result of this indexing for every slice of z.  So naturally I tried `z[:, i]`.  However, `z[:, i].shape` is `(5, 2, 9, 5)`, not what I would have expected, `(5, 9)`.

Since `z[:, i[0], i[1]]` gives the expected result, I tried `z[:, *i]` but was met with a SyntaxError.

In my full example I don't necessarily know how many arrays are in i, so hard-coding like `z[:, i[0], i[1]]` is not possible.

**Question:**

Is it possible to achieve something like `z[:, *i]` that gives the same result as `z[:, i[0], i[1], i[2], ... i[n-1]]` in case i has n arrays in it?

Comment: I just answered this question a couple hours ago (coincidence?). `z[:, *i]` should work on python 3.11+, for older versions `z[(slice(None), *i)]`

Comment: I think it is a coincidence; the recency might be why I couldn't find the answer!

Comment: No worries, that's an interesting question in any case ;)